# Detect Transparency Value in Str

Tags: php, regex, string

How would I check if a string is a valid transparency value with regex (e.g. `1.0` or `0.01`) with regex? I tried a few methods, but they don't match appropriately.

Valid ranges: `[0-1].[01-99]`

`(?<!\S)\d(?![^.])` is what I am currently trying:

```
<?php 

$vals = array('1.0','0.3','0.04','10.2','2,2','0.8');

foreach ( $vals as $v ):
    echo (rgbv($v)) ? $v.' is valid<br />' : $v.' is NOT valid<br />';
endforeach;

function rgbv($str) {
    return preg_match('([0-1].\d+)', $str);
}

?>
```

Outputs:

```
1.0 is valid
0.3 is valid
0.04 is valid
10.2 is valid <-- Should be invalid
2,2 is NOT valid
0.8 is valid
```

Comment: A typo. Valid is what I meant.

Comment: yep, i really don't know about that.

Comment: Would this work? ([0-1].\d+) with global tag set

Comment: Almost, but not quite

`1.0 is valid
0.3 is valid
0.04 is valid
10.2 is valid
2,2 is NOT valid
0.8 is valid` Posted example code.

Comment: @AvinashRaj the point is I don't have any "valid" examples. So there is a invalid example. Lol I don't think you understand the question.

Comment: To be perfectly clear, it looks like what you are checking is [CSS opacity alpha values, which should not be greater than `1.0`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/opacity).

Comment: It's a RGB transparency value, hardly native to CSS, but yes. That's why I added the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `'([0-1].\d+)'` try...

```
'/^(0\.\d{1,2}|1\.0{1,2})$/'
```

..., which tests successfully using your otherwise-original code...

```
<?php 

$vals = array('1.0','0.3','0.04','10.2','2,2','0.8');

foreach ( $vals as $v ):
    echo (rgbv($v)) ? $v.' is valid<br />' : $v.' is NOT valid<br />';
endforeach;

function rgbv($str) {
    return preg_match('/^(0\.\d{1,2}|1\.0{1,2})$/', $str);
}

?>
```

..., producing the following output as desired:

```
1.0 is valid
0.3 is valid
0.04 is valid
10.2 is NOT valid
2,2 is NOT valid
0.8 is valid
```

You can [test the updated pattern on Ideone](http://ideone.com/9SeZZ3).

Note that it looks like you are testing for [CSS opacity alpha values, which should not be greater than `1.0`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/opacity).

Comment: This seems to be the trick. And yes, they are a opacity value, but it's not native to CSS in the least. RGB, and RGBA are seen in several languages.

Comment: Yes, similar opacity values definitely show up in other contexts.  I am fond of them in Inkscape for example. :)  I was just guessing that CSS was the specific context here.  Glad you have something that works for your needs now!  Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest this one: `'/^(0(?:\.\d+)?|1(?:\.0+)?)$/'` since `0`, `1`, `0.000000` and `1.00000000` are valid values.

Comment: Yeah this is for a game thingy, but also for CSS now that it is workable and I can put a limit on RGB input xD

Answer (score 1):

You may try this regex.

```
^(?!.*\.00$|0\.0$)[01]\.\d{1,2}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fK2mF3/3)

Answer (score 1):

This one:

`~^(?:0|1)\.[0-9]{1,2}$~`

where `~` is regex delimeter

Comment: This regex will fail because `1.99` will be valid when it isn't a valid value.

Comment: That is a issue. Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

So, at most two digits after the decimal point? Is the decimal point necessary? Is 1.00 the highest value? You might try the following:

```
(?:^|[^\d.])(0(?:\.\d{0,2})?|1(?:\.0{0,2})?)(?=([^\d.]|$))
```

The only difficulty would be where the transparency value is followed by a period (as in ending a sentence). Any of the following values would be accepted by this regex:

```
0.00
1.00
0.02
0.04
0.
0
1.
1.0
```

The following would be rejected:

```
2.0
1.01
```

[Please see Regex Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/sO0mB8/1).